# How can we run If else statement inside JQuery Append Function.?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This is my append function i want to run the if else statement inside this. The data is coming  in the json format.

```
$('#allproduct')
   .append('
    <div class="add-to-cart">'+if(item.quantity >0){+'<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
    Add to Cart
    </a>'+}else{+'
   a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
   SOLD OUT
    </a>'+}+'
    </div>');
```

Comment: Why to run if elese statement inside append. Prepare html in var and then append that var

Comment: Where is the if? Can't you post a minimal example?

Comment: Also, you add a `php` tag to the question. Why can't you do it on the server side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just declare a html variable, build it however you want then pass it to the append function.

However, if you insist on using an `if` condition inside the buildup of the string, you could use [ternary condition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) as:

```
.append('< some html >' +
        (item.quality > 0 ? 'a possibility' : 'another possibility') +
        '</some html>');
```

where `<some html>` will contain `a possibility` if quality>0 and `another possibility` if condition is false

Adapted to your case:

```
$('#allproduct').append(
   '<div class="add-to-cart">'+
   ( item.quantity >0 ? 
        '<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
             'Add to Cart' +
        '</a>' 
   :
        '<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
             'SOLD OUT' +
        '</a>' 
    ) +
</div>');
```

Comment: `'html'+if(item.quantity>0){+'<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">Add to Cart</a>'+else{+'<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">Sold Out</a>'}'html'`     ** so Is this what you are saying?**

Comment: no, you cannot use `if-else` during the concatenation

Comment: I added this code into a button and it works. Thanks, mate. 

'</td><td><button type="button"'+
                                                 (
                                                    data.admin_verified_at == 1 ?
                                                     'disabled="disabled"'
                                                   :
                                                    ''
                                                 ) + 'class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="approve" data-id="'+data.id+'">Approve</button>

Answer (score 1):

You can build the HTML string first, and then append:

```
var htmlStr = '...';
if(condition) htmlStr += '...';
...

$('#allproduct').append(htmlStr);
```

Comment: what i actually want is.  if(item.quantity >0 ){<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
    Add to Cart
    </a>}else{<a class="item'+item.id+'" title="Add to Cart" href="javascript:void(0)">
    Sold Out
    </a>}